# How to assign title to each of the id rows to assist with filtering full table in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

If I have a pivot table like above I want to be able to filter on the names like "1st Advantage FCU" and get the relevant ID#s for that title. How can I do this in excel?

This is just a snippet of thousands of records.

please help!

Expected Result :
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve ... could you please show us your expected result (s. [repro])

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),A1,B2)` in `A2` and drag down?

Comment: I don’t believe what you have is a “pivot table.”  If the data snippet was in a pivot table you’d just create your desired result via the tabular settings for the table.

Comment: Are you using office 365 ? or is it an older version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your Data Starting from A1

```
  |    A     |        B       |        C       |
  | -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
 1| f1 names | row labels     | total bins     |
 2| FORMULA  | 1st Adv FCU    |        3       |
```

Put this Formula in A2 and Drag it downword

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=INDEX($C$2:C2,MATCH(A1,$B$2:B2,0))+1,B2,A1),B2)
```